# UWP: Get exact position of mouse (pointer) click inside image

Tags: c#, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a ContentDialog where I have an image and another image overlayed to place a watermark on it:

```
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Grid>
            <Image x:Name="ImageOriginal" Source="{x:Bind OriginalImage, Mode=OneWay}" MinHeight="120" MinWidth="160"/>
            <Image x:Name="ImageOverlay" Source="{x:Bind OverlayImage, Mode=OneWay}" MinHeight="120" MinWidth="160" PointerPressed="ImageOverlay_PointerPressed" />
        </Grid>
        ...
```

So the goal was, to place a text (centered horizontally and vertically) on the clicked position.

```
        private void ImageOverlay_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            var point = e.GetCurrentPoint(ImageOverlay);
            var pointPosition = new Windows.Foundation.Point((int)point.Position.X, (int)point.Position.Y);
            Position = new PointF((float)pointPosition.X, (float)pointPosition.Y);

            UpdateOverlayImage();
        }
```

(PointF) is a floating point point of ImageSharp. With the code above my text placement is always a bit off, like 50 pixels in each direction.

I also tried it with the following code, but this just makes the text placed wrongly in the opposite direction:

```
            GeneralTransform transform = ImageOverlay.TransformToVisual(Window.Current.Content);
            Windows.Foundation.Point coordinatePointToWindow = transform.TransformPoint(pointPosition);
```

*Update:*

Someone wanted to know, how I draw the text,s o here it is, this code is inside `UpdateOverlayImage()`:

```
        var watermarkedImage = OverlayImageBase.Clone(ctx => ctx.ApplyWatermark(font, tbWatermarkText.Text, color, Position));
        OverlayImage = watermarkedImage.ToBitmap();
```

And the `ApplyWatermark` extension method looks like this:

```
        public static IImageProcessingContext ApplyWatermark(this IImageProcessingContext processingContext,
            Font font,
            string text,
            Color color,
            PointF position)
        {
            var textGraphicOptions = new TextGraphicsOptions(true)
            {
                ColorBlendingMode = SixLabors.ImageSharp.PixelFormats.PixelColorBlendingMode.Normal,
                HorizontalAlignment = SixLabors.Fonts.HorizontalAlignment.Center,
                VerticalAlignment = SixLabors.Fonts.VerticalAlignment.Center,
            };
            return processingContext.DrawText(textGraphicOptions, text, font, color, position);
        }
```

Any ideas why my coordinates are off?

Comment: May I know how you placed the text on the clicked position? Can you provide a simple sample that can be reproduced for us to test?

Comment: I just noticed, that it doesn't happen on every image. I had the issue with a photo set as ImageOriginal but not with a gif, but I doubt it has to do with the file type, maybe because the dimensions are a bit different...

Comment: Is it always 50 pix off? Did you try to resize the window (with image). My guess is that something is "wrong" with image pixel size vs xaml Image element size.  Can you provide minimal sample project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out what was wrong. As the displayed image inside the ContentDialog is scaled, the coordinates of the drawn text cannot be directly the same coordintes as received from the pointer pressed event (of course).

So we have to calculate the relative to the size of the scaling. This is how I could solve it:

```
        private void ImageOverlay_PointerPressed(object sender, Windows.UI.Xaml.Input.PointerRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.Handled = true;

            PointerPoint ptrPt = e.GetCurrentPoint(ImageOverlay);

            // As the image is scaled we have to caluclate the position inside the image based on the position of the pointer pressed
            float imagePressedX = (float)(OriginalImage.PixelWidth / ImageOverlay.ActualWidth * ptrPt.Position.X);
            float imagePressedY = (float)(OriginalImage.PixelHeight / ImageOverlay.ActualHeight * ptrPt.Position.Y); ;
            Position = new PointF(imagePressedX, imagePressedY);

            UpdateOverlayImage();
        }
```